# I want to show the last photos of my instagram on my website, can I do that with their API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm using a javascript code (instafeed.js) to connect to the Instagram API and get the last photos of my Instagram account. The problem is that the thing works for a few days and then the token I got from instagram "expires" or something and it stops working. It throws me Uncaught Error: Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid.

I believe (I might be wrong) it's because I never sent my "app" for review and they are giving me a "sandbox mode" token. Or should I be able to use their API for this simple thing without approval?

Should I send my website for review or is this not an intended use of their API? And if it's not, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use API in sandbox mode to access your latest 20 posts. You dont need to get reviewed.

Not sure about access_token expiring, in live mode it never expires, so I expect sandbox to be same